# Windows 7 Ctrl + # Hotkey That Moves Screen Between Monitors

Tags: windows, windows-7

Does anyone know how to disable the ctrl + # Windows hotkey that moves the active screen from one monitor to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hotkeys were from my graphics card driver.  I disabled it using Windows' video display properties

Answer (score 1):

The keys you are most likely looking for would be the Windows Key+Shift+Left or Right Arrow, without shift the arrow keys will still move between monitors, but will dock to the side of each monitor first. The keyboard shortcuts for Windows 7 can be found [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/Windows7/Keyboard-shortcuts).

Answer (score 1):

The key sequence you are referring to is part of the Aero Snap features.  You can disable this, but be aware that it will also stop you from being able to drag a window to the top of the screen and have it maximize automatically or use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and  <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to snap a window to half of the screen.  If you still want to disable Aero Snap, you can do so like this:

1. Click **Start**, **Control Panel**
2. Click **Ease of Access** and click **Ease of Access Center**
3. Click one of the following options:

   - **Make the mouse easier to use**
   - **Make the keyboard easier to use**
   - **Make it easier to focus on tasks**
4. Check the checkbox for the following option:

   > Prevent windows from being automatically arranged when moved to the edge of the screen
5. Click OK, and close the Ease of Access Center